# Laravel: Nested relationship method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following models:

### users

- id
- name

### organisation_members

- id
- organisation_id (FK to organisations)
- user_id (FK to users)
- *unqiue(organisation_id, user_id)*

### organisations

- id
- name

A user can be a member to many organisations.

My models are written as follows

```
class User extends Model {
    public function organisationMembers(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrganisationMember::class);
    }
  
    public function organisations()
    {
        // TODO: how do I do this one
    }
}
```

```
class OrganisationMember extends Model {
    public function organisation(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Organisation::class);
    }

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Organisation extends Model {
    public function organisationMembers(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(organisationMember::class);
    }
}
```

How can I write a relationship method in the `User` model for `organisations`?

Comment: I am really confused, you have a `many-to-many` relation not a `one-to-many`, `organisation_members` is the relation between `user` and `organisation`, so it should be named `organisation_user`, and instead of `hasMany`, you should be using `belongsToMany`, so users can have multiple organisations and the organisations can have multiple users... Read [this part of the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) so you understand what I am trying to explain.

Comment: do note that the `belongsToMany` takes the intermediate table name as the second argument, so it's not entirely necessary to rename the table although renaming as @matias suggested might be the Laravel best practice.

Comment: @user3532758 yes, I am disregadirng second parameter as it is not following laravel standards

Comment: You dont create the relation, you already create a many to many between the User and the Organisation. There is no need to create a relation with the public function organisations.

Comment: @Collin So how would I get all the users organisations?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @matiaslauriti comment the answer is:

```
class User extends Model {
    public function organisationMembers(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrganisationMember::class);
    }
  
    public function organisations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Organisation::class, 'organisation_members');
    }
}
```

Comment: `User` can have many `OrganisationMember` and a `OrganisationMember` can have a single `Organisation`. Therefore the relationship between `User`  and `Organisation` is a many to many relationship, as a user can be a member of many organisations.

Comment: It is basically the same example as the Laravel docs, which I didn't realise: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I tried `HasOneThrough` and `HasManyThrough` but I believe the structure of these models are slightly different: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through